# Is a black hole a single particle or a bunch of particles that binds together?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, event-horizon, singularities

We know that in a neutron star all electrons and protons combine together and make neutrons because of the gravitational pulls. We also know that a black hole is much denser than a neutron star, we can calculate the density of a neutron star accurately but we can't calculate the density of a black hole's core, because we can't measure the radius of a black hole core. So I made a conclusion that there's a  possibility that a black hole core is a single particle, but since my knowledge of black holes is limited and I'm not an expert, can anyone tell me if a black hole is a single particle, or if it is a bunch of particles which are bigger and  denser than neutrons and binds together by a strong force?

Answer (score 3):

Black holes are not objects per se. They are not made of particles or anything of the sort. They are regions of spacetime.

Suppose an observer who lives forever. One might think that, after an infinite amount of time, this observer will have seen everything that has ever happened in the Universe. One just have to wait long enough so that the light from those events reach them, right?

Wrong. There are observers who, even after infinite time, will not have seen all of spacetime. This might happen either because the observer is in some sort of "confined region". For example, the expansion of the Universe makes it impossible for light from some regions of the Universe to reach us, so that there is a maximum region of spacetime we can see due to the expansion "dragging away" the other regions from us. Furthermore, there are regions that many observers can't see. More specifically, there are regions such that none of the infinitely many observers that go infinitely far in an infinite amount of time will see. This is due to the fact that nothing, not even light, can escape those regions. Those regions are precisely what we call black holes. They are the collections of events that outside observers will not see even after an infinite amount of time has passed.

Notice that this makes no reference to any composition or matter. The black hole is not an object made of something, it is a region in spacetime. [This PBS Spacetime video](https://youtu.be/vNaEBbFbvcY) discusses these notions extremely well.

In the case of a black hole formed out of a collapsing star, what happens according to General Relativity is that all of the matter that falls into the black hole will reach its singularity. In this sense, one could say that all of the matter is concentrated in the singularity. However, there is a catch: singularities are not a point in spacetime. Hence, the matter, or whatever you could say that comprises the "core" of the black hole, isn't actually in spacetime. In fact, the Schwarzschild solution (which describes non-rotating, uncharged black holes) is a vacuum soltution: it is derived assuming the absence of matter in spacetime.

**Remark:** technically, there is matter in the spacetimes of charged black holes, but that matter is just the electromagnetic field, so it doesn't actually correspond to any matter that could be said to form the black hole.

Answer (score 0):

A (Schwarzschild) black hole is made from curved spacetime, around a singularity. Matter that has reached the singularity is destroyed, at least that's what Kip Thorne says: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oj1AfkPQa6M .

Answer (score 0):

An experimental physicist's answer:

We have by now a fairly complete standard model for particle physics, and a theory that shows that classical theories emerge naturally from the underlying quantum mechanical frame that models particle physics, [the standard model.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)

We also have the theory of General Relativity that has been shown to be very successful in fitting and predicting astrophysical data. This theory predicts black holes, how they evolved from collapsed stars, and objects in the cosmos fitting the predictions have been observed. One of the predictions for a black hole is that whatever matter enters the event horizon, it is a point of no return, and the mass, quantum numbers etc disappear in the singularity.

> So I made a conclusion that there's a possibility that a black hole core is a single particle,

If so it would be one with enormous mass concentrated in one spacetime point.

The black hole has a mass that can be calculated from gravitational observations but there is no way to study what has happened to the individual particles that entered the horizon. They are just an energy and momentum [four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) added to the existing one of the black hole.

> or if it is a bunch of particles which are bigger and denser than neutrons and binds together by a strong force?

Certainly, within the existing theory of GR  this cannot be true, as explained by other answers.